# bootstrap 4 : button groups with a.btn in the middle

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have a button group but the middle button is a link so it should b `a` tag (i can change its button and use js to navigate but I prefer not to )
here is the code

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="btn-group nospiner">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning yekan create-wallet"><i class="mdi mdi-arrow-down-bold"></i> down</button>
  <a href="link.php" type="button" class="btn btn-warning yekan pjax"> center</a>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning yekan ">up  <i class="mdi mdi-arrow-up-bold"></i> </button>
</div>
```

here is the result

[image]

as you can see the middle btn has a border and gradient, how can I change it so it would look like buttons? i've tried adding `border:none` to all `.btn` and button group it didn't work

Comment: can you please add your code in detail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply remove `type=button` from the `a`

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="btn-group nospiner" >
       <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning yekan create-wallet"><i class="mdi mdi-arrow-down-bold"></i> down</button>
       <a  href="link.php"  class="btn btn-warning yekan pjax" > center</a>
       <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning yekan " >up  <i class="mdi mdi-arrow-up-bold"></i> </button>
   </div>
```